# Efficient 2D edge detection in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I know that this problem has been solved before, but I've been great difficulty finding any literature describing the algorithms used to process this sort of data.  I'm essentially doing some edge finding on a set of 2D data.  I want to be able to find a couple points on an eye diagram (generally used to qualify high speed communications systems), and as I have had no experience with image processing I am struggling to write efficient methods.

As you can probably see, these diagrams are so called because they resemble the human eye.  They can vary a great deal in the thickness, slope, and noise, depending on the signal and the system under test.  The measurements that are normally taken are jitter (the horizontal thickness of the crossing region) and eye height (measured at either some specified percentage of the width or the maximum possible point).  I know this can best be done with image processing instead of a more linear approach, as my attempts so far take several seconds just to find the left side of the first crossing.  Any ideas of how I should go about this in Python?  I'm already using NumPy to do some of the processing.

Here's some [example data](http://www.4shared.com/get/ReK7OxmV/example_data.html), it is formatted as a 1D array with associated x-axis data.  For this particular example, it should be split up every 666 points (2 * int((1.0 / 2.5e9) / 1.2e-12)), since the rate of the signal was 2.5 GB/s, and the time between points was 1.2 ps.

Thanks!

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: your data paste didn't quite work...

Comment: Assuming that you have the original data used to generate the graph, maybe you would have better success using that data directly than analyzing a rendered graph.

Comment: The amount of data I have is quite massive, on the scale of > 300,000 points.  It takes quite a long time to analyze with any method, but I figured that treating it like a 2D image would be easier than just treating it like a bunch of numbers

Comment: Since a 2D image is nothing more than a bunch of numbers, I wouldn't be so confident.

Comment: Google will throw up loads of stuff for this. The Sobel operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is a simple (e.g. computationally cheap) one.

Comment: @Evpok I know that I can figure out how to transform my data directly into a bitmap, which would compress it greatly, and the processing would then be a lot more efficient, as I can test by simply importing these images using `PIL.Image` and using `ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES`.  It's at this point that I am out of knowledge.  The Sobel Operator looks promising, but it only gives me another image back. I need to know what efficient methods already exist for finding the actual position, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Dumping it to an image is nothing more than smart way of rounding (with one unit defined by the graphs resolution).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (Open Computer Vision)? It's widely used and has a Python binding.

Not to be a PITA, but are you **sure** you wouldn't be better off with a numerical approach? All the tools I've seen for eye-diagram analysis go the numerical route; I haven't seen a single one that analyzes the image itself.

You say your algorithm is painfully slow on that dataset -- my next question would be why. Are you looking at an oversampled dataset? (I'm guessing you are.) And if so, have you tried decimating the signal first? That would at the very least give you fewer samples for your algorithm to wade through.

Comment: I have to have as accurate as possible of measurements.  The jitter needs to be within 1 ps (I actually am currently interpolating to get more exact, not just the closest discrete point), and as these are actually simulated eye diagrams, the amount of data that I have to input is quite large in order to get an accurate measurement out.

Comment: I should point out that if you're looking at a set of samples from an analog signal that's already been A/D converted, interpolating between samples won't make your measurements any more accurate. That's why we oversample signals in the first place. Also, 300,000 data points isn't that much in the DSP world. That's the equivalent of about seven seconds of audio sampled at 44.1 kHz.

Comment: Its less than a nanosecond for me.  While its not a lot in the DSP world, its a lot of data to have to process.  I believe that if I can quickly convert this data to an image in memory (these were generated with matplotlib, which is significantly slower), then it should be relatively easy to deal with.

Comment: And edit on my last comment, I had a decimal place moved.  It's somewhere around 360 nanoseconds for me.  I'm generally working with > 3 GHz signals.

Answer (score 1):

just going down your route for a moment, if you read those images into memory, as they are, wouldn't it be pretty easy to do two flood fills (starting centre and middle of left edge) that include all "white" data.  if the fill routine recorded maximum and minimum height at each column, and maximum horizontal extent, then you have all you need.

in other words, i think you're over-thinking this.  edge detection is used in complex "natural" scenes when the edges are unclear.  here you edges are so completely obvious that you don't need to enhance them.